# new 22.04 install cannot play sound on speakers

Tags: sound, 22.04

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04.  The Bang & Olufsen speakers aren't playing sound.

I've gone through https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sound-nosound.html.en but nothing there helps.

I can get sound on headphones, but when I pull the headphones out, the sound is gone, even though the volume is set to max.

`Speaker - sof-hda-dsp` shows in the settings as being recognized, but it's not being used.  When I pull the headphones out, the `Output device` switches.

`sudo lspci -v` gives:

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 51ca (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8bdd
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 204, IOMMU group 15
    Memory at 601d1d0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 601d000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
```

Similarly, I have an older laptop with a nearly identical setup, that actually works:

```
lspci -v | fgrep -m1 -A19 '00:1f.3'
```

gives

```
   00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 154
    Memory at b431c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at b4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
```

Perhaps switching the kernel driver in use is the key? How can I do that, if it will help?

[Sound card not detecting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471433/sound-card-not-detecting) and the command `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r `alsa-base alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-oss alsa-source alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils alsamixergui` didn't fix the problem.

[How to install Bang and Olufsen Audio drivers for HP laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873881/how-to-install-bang-and-olufsen-audio-drivers-for-hp-laptop) failed to solve my problem.

[No sound on headphones with sof-hda-dsp audio on ubuntu (and variants)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253498/no-sound-on-headphones-with-sof-hda-dsp-audio-on-ubuntu-and-variants) also failed.

[Audio output doesn't switch when headphones connect or disconnect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1448046/audio-output-doesnt-switch-when-headphones-connect-or-disconnect) didn't help either.

[Ubuntu 20.04 - No sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231524/ubuntu-20-04-no-sound) also failed

`cat /proc/asound/cards` produces the following output:

```
 0 [sofhdadsp      ]: sof-hda-dsp - sof-hda-dsp
                      HP-HPEnvyLaptop17_cw0xxx-Type1ProductConfigId-8BDD



sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

and add

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

as suggested [Ubuntu 20.04 - No sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231524/ubuntu-20-04-no-sound) also failed.

using sof-bin as suggested by [Sound card not detected - Ubuntu 20.04 - sof-audio-pci](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243369/sound-card-not-detected-ubuntu-20-04-sof-audio-pci/1424600?noredirect=1#comment2591203_1424600) also failed.

I'm also getting

```
[    0.475866] pci 0000:00:07.0: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
[    0.476486] pci 0000:00:07.2: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
```

during the boot process.  Is this connected to why my speakers don't work?

I have done the standard `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` to no avail, as well.

when I grep for audio within `dmesg`:

```
[    0.116257] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    7.147645] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[    7.147677] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Digital mics found on Skylake+ platform, using SOF driver
[    7.147696] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    7.148080] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
[    8.341717] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    8.407947] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode
[    8.441644] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: hda codecs found, mask 5
[    8.441649] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: using HDA machine driver skl_hda_dsp_generic now
[    8.441653] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DMICs detected in NHLT tables: 2
[    8.442691] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
[    8.442695] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:21:0
[    8.442697] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: FW ABI is more recent than kernel
[    8.442701] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: unknown sof_ext_man header type 3 size 0x30
[    8.538642] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
[    8.538647] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:21:0
[    8.538649] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: FW ABI is more recent than kernel
[    8.555720] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Topology: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:21:0
[    8.555726] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: warn: topology ABI is more recent than kernel
[    8.585014] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: autoconfig for ALC245: line_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    8.585021] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    8.585023] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    8.585025] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    8.585026] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    inputs:
[    8.585028] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:      Mic=0x19
[    8.634984] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: ASoC: sink widget AIF1TX overwritten
[    8.634992] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: ASoC: source widget AIF1RX overwritten
```

I have also tried adding `snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1` to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` but that changed nothing https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=275737

`cat /proc/asound/cards` gives the output:

```
 0 [sofhdadsp      ]: sof-hda-dsp - sof-hda-dsp
                      HP-HPEnvyLaptop17_cw0xxx-Type1ProductConfigId-8BDD
```

`sudo aplay -l`

gives the output:

```
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 4: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 5: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

How can I get the sound working on my speakers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this a well-known problem with no easy fix, yet. See [here](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Audio/No-sound-from-internal-speakers-using-Linux/m-p/8478057/highlight/true#M119011) for details. The laptop in question in that post is a HP ENVY x360 15-ey0xxx, which also uses Bang & Olufsen speakers. This Q&A post is quite active, with the [latest reply](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Audio/No-sound-from-internal-speakers-using-Linux/m-p/8818694/highlight/true#M122238) as of this writing dated yesterday (July 25th, 2023). I did some digging through it, and it seems that you have two options:

1. Update your Linux kernel version to 6.3.2 as indicated by [this reply](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Audio/No-sound-from-internal-speakers-using-Linux/m-p/8722257/highlight/true#M122054). To do so, you can follow the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1455144/1178898). However, as explained in these answers, it is not recommended. Therefore, you may want to install a non-LTS version of Ubuntu instead, such as 23.04 or 23.10 when it comes out.
2. As indicated in [this reply](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Audio/No-sound-from-internal-speakers-using-Linux/m-p/8818694/highlight/true#M122238), you can install a DKMS module that fixes the problem by following the instructions [here](https://github.com/xoocoon/hp-15-ew0xxx-snd-fix). However, for this option, it is extremely important to note the following warning under the reply:

```
Thanks for the patch, but note that this change can't be taken.
It's dangerous and may burn speakers on other machines that don't use
this configuration.

For now, those info relies on the BIOS ACPI setup with _DSD entry, and
vendors should fix it with BIOS updates.

There have been already discussions how to deal with vendors who don't
cooperate well.
```

I think both of these options are not ideal, and I would personally wait until this problem is fixed in a future release of Ubuntu.

Comment: thnx, I'll check out 23.04

Comment: @con actually, according to [this post](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/lunar-lobster-release-notes/31910), Ubuntu 23.04 comes with Linux kernel version 6.2, which is older than the 6.3.2 that the reply mentions. Therefore, there is no guarantee that installing Ubuntu 23.04 will solve the problem.

Comment: indeed, the upgrade to 23.04 didn't solve the problem, but because 23.10 is supposed to use kernel 6.5, which is > 6.3.2, then the problem may be solved in October.  I'll wait until then to fix the problem, and just stick to headphones

Comment: @con could you update us when you install Ubuntu 23.10 and let us know if it solves the problem?

Comment: I will update you when I install 23.10, whenever it becomes available

Comment: @con did you get a chance to [install 23.10](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) to see if fixes the problem? Another thing you can try before you do this is to install the [OEM kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/OEMKernel) on 22.04 by running `apt install linux-oem-22.04c` to see if this fixes the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to upgrade, but 23.10 isn't showing as available.  I've checked to make sure that my software sources are checked to all releases, but 23.10 still isn't showing :(

Comment: @con don't worry about it. It turns out that it's not actually [available yet](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/announcement-ubuntu-desktop-23-10-release-image-is-being-updated-to-resolve-a-malicious-translation-incident/39365?_ga=2.141723895.410373919.1697414531-1610706413.1697225992).

Comment: @con sorry for the persistent mentions, but did you get a chance to try 23.10 out? It should be fixed now. You could also try installing the OEM kernel as mentioned in my other comment above.

Comment: `sudo do-release-upgrade` says that "No new release found".  I'm aware of the `-d` option for devel releases, but I've done devel releases before, and I had a lot of problems with them. I've upgraded the kernel to 6.2.0-35-generic and the problem persists. Hopefully the new release will be available soon

Comment: @con I see. Thanks for trying! Have you tried to install the OEM kernel using `apt install linux-oem-22.04c`? If not, see [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/OEMKernel) and let me know if this works.

Comment: I'm unable to install `linux-oem-22.04c`, I tried several other iterations of `23.10` and `6.2`, but none of them worked :(

Comment: @con thanks for following up! I’m sure future readers who come here will appreciate this.

Comment: I've successfully updated to 23.10.  Unfortunately, the speakers are still not working :( with kernel 6.5.0-10-generic

Comment: @con That is unfortunate. Oh well, at least we tried...

Comment: @con this is a long shot, but it turns out that the HP Zbook Studio can be purchased with Ubuntu 22.04 pre-loaded. This laptop also comes with Bang & Olufsen speakers, so I'm thinking that, if you install the kernel that's installed on the Studio, then the speakers should theoretically work. The details for the kernel running on the Studio are [here](https://ubuntu.com/certified/202201-29844), which is the `6.1.0-1020-oem` kernel. Can you try installing this version of the kernel and see if this fixes the problem?

Comment: @con more specifically, based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1401069/1178898), while you have Ubuntu 22.04 installed, can you try running `sudo apt install linux-modules-6.1.0-1020-oem` and then run `sudo apt install linux-image-6.1.0-1020-oem`? You can find out more details about this kernel image [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/linux-image-6.1.0-1020-oem).

Comment: I think that I can get to that soon, thanks for your help!

Comment: @con no worries. I also think you will need to run `sudo reboot` after the other commands above.